# Mocking a method that uses external classes, mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm new to mockito and just trying to understand how it works.

I have a method that I want to test. The method instantiates multiple classes to use its methods.

e.g.

```
methodToTest{
 class1 c1 = new class1();
 class2 c2 = new class2();
 class3 c4 = new class3();

c1.method1;
c2.method2;
c3.method3;

more logic 

...

return result
}
```

I understand that in order to test this method I need to mock the classes. Doe this mean I need to decouple it and pass in each class as a parameter to the method?
I want to avoid having a method that uses a large list of parameters that will only really be necessary when mocking.

Perhaps I've missed something.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: _Doe this mean I need to decouple it and pass in each class as a parameter to the method?_ That would be a good way to solve this, yes.

Comment: If you mean "pass in each object", then yes, that would be a totally reasonable thing to do.  Or you could use a factory method, or a factory helper.  Check out [my article about this](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation), on the Mockito blog.

Comment: Thanks Keppil and David, I bit the bullet and added the mock classes in as parameters. I overloaded the method with a smaller set of parameters so that client classes don't have to instantiate the classes when it runs live.

Answer (score 3):

My standard solution here is to add a method which instantiates the class:

```
public ClassToTest {
    methodToTest{
        class1 c1 = newClass1();
        ...
    }

    class1 newClass1() {
        return new Class1();
    }
}
```

The new method is `protected` or package private and I simply override it in my unit test to inject the mocks:

```
@Test
public void testFoo() {
    ClassToTest inst = new ClassToTest() {
        class1 newClass1() {
            return new Class1(); // <--- you can mock here
        }            
    };
}
```

Comment: I like it! Actually using this style you can get away without using mockito at all. Old school mocking. Sometimes it is much more straightforward then the mockito counterpart.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your response. I'm dont think I understand what you mean though. If you instantiate the new class privately then it is not mocked which means when your test methodToTest,it would be running a real version of class1 right? Perhaps a more in depth example would help if you dont mind?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing different objects of classes to method you could actually mock when new object is created.
eg

```
Class1 class1 = Mockito.mock(Class1.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(Class1.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(class1);
```

At the top of the test class write this annotation

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Class1.class})
public class Class1Test {

----------- some code-------
}
```

Follow the link
https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13

Hope this will solve your problem.
Ask in case of query.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that you're adding a whole new library into the mix?  This isn't Mockito.

Comment: I myself came through the same problem. After using PowerMockito, i think its definately worth. You can do a lot more things that Mockito alone cannot provide. Try it once. Mockito and PowerMockito can work together so there's no issue. Its simple. Just give it  a try.